# How to solve React Vite 404 Error on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, oauth, spotify, vite, vercel

I'm new to Stack Overflow and currently building an application using React Vite. I'm integrating the Spotify API into my application and implementing the Authorization feature using the Authorization Code with PKCE Flow guide provided by Spotify [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-pkce-flow).

The application works perfectly fine on my local machine. Now, I'm trying to deploy the app on Vercel. I have set up my environment variables in the Vercel project settings. As per the Spotify documentation, I need to specify the `redirect_uri` to which the OAuth service will redirect the user. I have set the `redirect_uri` value as `http://localhost:5173/callback` in my `.env` file locally. In the Vercel environment variables, I have set the `redirect_uri` value as `https://project.vercel.app/callback`.

However, when I run the application on Vercel, the flow works fine until I click the "Agree" button on the Spotify service. It then redirects to `https://project.vercel.app/callback?code=...&state=...`, but Vercel gives a 404 Not Found error.

I don't know if the react router is the problem or no, but here's my react router looks like

```ts
const routes = [
   {
      path: "/callback",
      Component: AuthCallback,
   }
]

export const router = createBrowserRouter([...routes]);
```

I've tried double check if there's any typo when I specified the `redirect_uri` on my local machine, Vercel environment variable, and Spotify developer dashboard. And I'm sure this is not a typo problem, and I don't really know what causing this issue.

I would greatly appreciate any thoughts or solutions you might have to solve this issue. Thank's.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution for this issue, you just need to add a file called `vercel.json` in the root of the folder and paste this code.

```json
{
    "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }]
}
```

This configuration will prevent your web application to have a 404 error when you refresh the page or when you open other routes.

Comment: This didn't work but I got another error.