# How to deploy ClerkJS used with Vite using Vercel?

Tags: reactjs, vite, vercel, clerk

I am trying to test out how to deploy ClerkJS Apps when used with Vite. I have created a sample project here:
https://github.com/shivpreet16/authentication-clerk-react

I have been following this doc: https://clerk.com/docs/deployments/vercel

However, after deployment, when I click on 'Protected Page', it shows me this:
[image: Error Screenshot]

```
if (!import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY) {
  throw new Error("Missing Publishable Key")
}

const clerkPubKey = import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY;
```

This is the code in `App.jsx` for getting the clerkPubKey. I have added an environment variable in Vercel called `VITE_REACT_APP_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY` that holds the value of my public key. However, it does not seem to be working correctly. Can someone help?

Comment: This guy figured out why here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76420555

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. When I deployed, the problem was with the redirection from Vercel, so what I did was make a vercel.json file and added:

```json
{  "rewrites": [{"source":"/(.*)", "destination": "/"}]}
```